# Mongodb collections data display blank on webpage with Crow

Tags: c++, mongodb, railway, crow

I have deployed to railway and mongodb collections named contacts is added with josn file. I want contacts' data display on webpage. Then I add a mongodb c++ drivers by create a dockerfile in hello_crow/bbox. I use the command`docker build --rm --no-cache --squash -t bbox:latest .` to build a image. It display a warning message:

```bash
WARNING: experimental flag squash is removed with BuildKit. You should squash inside build using a multi-stage Dockerfile for efficiency.
```

In hello_crow directory, main.cpp:

```cpp
#include "crow_all.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/oid.hpp>

#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/stdx.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/uri.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>

using bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_array;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_document;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::document;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::finalize;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_array;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_document;
using bsoncxx::builder::basic::kvp;
using mongocxx::cursor;
using namespace std;
using namespace crow;

crow::mustache::rendered_template getView(const string& filename, context& x)
{
    auto page=load("../public/" + filename + ".html");
    return page.render(x);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    crow::SimpleApp app;
    set_base(".");

    mongocxx::instance inst{};
    string mongoConnect=std::string(getenv("MONGO_URL"));
    mongocxx::client conn{mongocxx::uri{mongoConnect}};
    auto collection=conn["containers-us-west-175.railway.app:7978"]["contacts"];
       
    CROW_ROUTE(app, "/contact/<string>")
    ([&collection](string email)
    {
        set_base(".");
        auto doc=collection.find_one(make_document(kvp("email",email)));
        crow::json::wvalue dto;
        dto["contact"]=json::load(bsoncxx::to_json(doc.value().view())) ;
        return getView("contact", dto);;
    }); 
    
    CROW_ROUTE(app, "/contacts")
    ([&collection]()
    {
        set_base(".");
        mongocxx::options::find opts;
        opts.skip(9);
        opts.limit(10);
        auto docs=collection.find({}, opts);
        crow::json::wvalue dto;
        vector<crow::json::rvalue> contacts;
        contacts.reserve(10);

        for (auto doc : docs)
        {
            contacts.push_back(json::load(bsoncxx::to_json(doc)));
        }
        dto["contacts"] = contacts;
        return getView("contacts", dto);
    });

    CROW_ROUTE(app, "/")
    ([](const crow::request& req, crow::response& res)
    {
        sendHtml(res, "index");
    });

    char* port = getenv("PORT");
    uint16_t iPort = static_cast<uint16_t>(port != NULL? stoi(port): 18080);
    cout << "PORT = " << iPort << endl;
    app.port(iPort).multithreaded().run();
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(hello_crow)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
find_package(libmongocxx REQUIRED)

add_executable(hello_crow main.cpp)
target_include_directories(hello_crow PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(hello_crow ${Boost_LIBRARIES} Threads::Threads ${LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES})
```

In hello_crow/, I create a dockerfile as below.

```
FROM bbox:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/cppweb/hello_crow
COPY . .

WORKDIR /usr/src/cppweb/hello_crow/build
RUN cmake .
RUN make
CMD ["./hello_crow"]
```

I use the command`docker build --rm --no-cache --squash -t hello_crow:latest .` to build a image. Also have last warning.

```
hello_crow:
│  CMakeLists.txt
│  crow_all.h
│  Dockerfile
│  main.cpp
├─bbox
│      Dockerfile
├─build
│
└─public
    │  contact.html
    │  contacts.html
       index.html    
    ├─images
    │      cat.jfif
    │      jerry.png    
    ├─scripts
    │      test.js    
    └─styles
            style.css
```

When I run command `docker run -p 8080:8080 -e PORT=8080 -e MONGO_URL="mongodb://myusername:mypassword@containers-us-west-175.railway.app:7978" hello_crow:latest`. The webpage `localhost:8080` and `localhost:8080/about` displayed fine. But `localhost:8080/contacts` display blank.
Why mongdb collections can't display. How can I fix it?
Answer: change `getenv()` and conn[database name][contacts].The page `localhost:8080/contacts` diplays data fine.
Another issue:When use crow::mustacle to render page /contacts. I run `docker build` and `docker run` again.The page become blank, can't find contacts.html. How can I fix it?
Answer:Replce `load` to `load_unsafe` and add `set_base(".")` in contacts route. It can display data with table.
But when I add new `contact.html` in public,qerry email with `localhost:8080/contact/<email>`. Error message is "Template "../public/contact.html" not found.". Why I set it same to `contacts route`, but also not found? How can I fix it?

Comment: Is this code returning anything: `collection.find({},opts);`?

Comment: You remind me. I see another code `auto collection=conn[contain "heroku" word][contacts]`, so I use MONGO_URL's words after "@". I misunderstand it. In railway, my database is "test". Now it displays contacts' data. Thank you so much.

Comment: I use `docker build --rm --no-cache --squash -t bbox:latest .` have a warning. After I change `experimental falg` to true according docker doc, the warning is still here.

Comment: New issue is when I muse mustache `return page.render()`. The /contacts page display blank.

Answer (score 0):

Using load_unsafe is working for me.

```
crow::mustache::rendered_template getView(const string &filename, context &x) {
auto page=load_unsafe("../public/" + filename + ".html");
return page.render(x);
```

}